# How to multicast between different EC2 instances using Java MulticastSocket?

Tags: java, sockets, amazon-ec2, multicast

I have implemented a simple P2P multicast network where each peer connected to the network sends data to every other peer. In order to make it possible, I made use of Java MulticastSocket Class, so every peer joins a multicast group defined by an available for multicast IP address, and a port number.
I got some issues while trying to run the program using EC2 services, where each generated instance represents a peer of the network, because the peers are not able to communicate in so far as exchanged messages do not reach the receivers.
Hence, basically my question is: is there a way to make EC2 instances communicate to each other using Java MulticastSocket? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natively, you can't.

> **Q. Does Amazon VPC support multicast or broadcast?**
>
> No.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/faqs/

Same thing for [EC2 Classic](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=147439) (though there is hardly any reason you'd ever want to use that, if your account even allows it).

VPC looks like Ethernet, but it isn't.  Put a packet sniffer on and try a ping.  Watch the ARP traffic on both sides and you'll see something enlightening -- the source machine arps for the target and gets a response, but you'll see neither of these packets on the target machine.  The ARP response comes from the network infrastructure itself.

There's a <strike>work</strike>hackaround, if you're feeling crafty: you can build an overlay mesh network that transports multicast over unicast.

See https://aws.amazon.com/articles/6234671078671125